# Low Quality Answers Review- Automated Reports?

Tags: discussion

I am curious regarding the low quality answers queue. Are all posts manually reported, or is there some automated mechanism? I ask, because I see a lot of posts from regulars and established members that are either very too the point in answering the question or provide very good hints. I would hope other regulars aren't flagging them for providing help. Given that a lot of these types of posts get flagged (sorry I do not have any immediate examples to provide), is some sort of script flagging them for review based on brevity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an automated script which assigns posts a "low quality answer score" which is responsible for the majority of the posts in the queue. However, flagging a post as "very low quality" should also put it in the queue.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks for your response!

Comment: The auto-flagged answers also appear differently in the review queues: They'll be marked with something like "Low answer quality score [63]."

Comment: @T.Bongers That's probably in the 10K flag queue? I haven't seen such scores in the Low Quality Review queue (which is what ml0105 is asking about).

Comment: @user127096 Yes, you're quite right. As far as I know, there's no way to tell them apart in the usual Low Quality queue.